# Postgres, nodejs SELECT query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a sqlquery which is: `client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_varchar='userInput'")`.

`userInput = req.body.userInput` which reads from an inputbox in a jade file.

No matter what I try with different `''` or `""` around the variables I either get that it generates an error from every input or every input seems correct, although that input does not exist in the table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal answer is don't do that! Inserting raw user input is a great way to get hacked. Do you actually have an input value?

instead:

```
console.log("User Input is "+ userInput); // or add debug lib and debug("User Input....
client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_varchar = $1", [userInput]);
```

Also validate your query in psql from a command prompt

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same problem, wrong inputs is seen as correct.

Comment: Please see revised advice.